# WindowsAuthentification between 2 sites Issue

Tags: windows, authentication, iis

I've configured 2 sites on IIS with windows authentification
[image: 2Site]
I'm able to consume each site. But If I try to fetch from the test Web Site an URL of the Default Web Site,  I obtain a 401 UnAuthorize.

do I need to do something in order to transmit the authentification ?

best regards

Comment: Escalate to your domain administrators please. They can show you what changes are required to make delegation work.

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 401 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.